# Re-using a Nashorn ScriptEngine

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

I have the following code that I run on each HTTP request:

```
ScriptEngine jsEngine = ScriptEngineManager.new().getEngineByName("nashorn");
jsEngine.eval("some script");
jsEngine.invokeMethod(jsEngine.eval("foo"), "bar");
```

It works, but it's extremely inefficient as my unchanging JavaScript is evaluated every time. What's the proper way to re-use the evaluated JavaScript?

Comment: Related.  Nas Horn has cache for evaluated scripts. I guess, you are looking for much more than that. https://blogs.oracle.com/nashorn/entry/latest_news_from_the_nashorn

Comment: @Jayan I read that question, but CompiledScript has no way to invoke a method, you need to invoke it in the engine, so I don't understand what's the point of the CompiledScript and how this whole set up provides re-usability of the script.

Comment: Okay- I will delete that link..