# Nashorn MultiThread Programming

Tags: javascript, java, multithreading, testng, nashorn

Can you help me out if the following code will work in a multi-threaded application.

**Here is my Java Script that will be evaluated by Nashorn**

```
var Thread = Java.type("java.lang.Thread");
var referenceNumberValid = "0000";
var referenceNumberInvalid = "0001";

function validate (parameters) {
    var isValid = false;
    var statusCode;
    var referenceNumber = parameters.referenceNumber;
    var validateNumber = referenceNumber.substr(0, 7);
    var sum = 0;

    for (ctr = 0; ctr < validateNumber.length; ctr++) {
        sum += parseInt(validateNumber.substr(ctr, 1));
    }

    var checkDigit = sum % 10;
    isValid = parseInt(referenceNumber.substr(7, 1)) == checkDigit;
    statusCode = isValid ? referenceNumberValid : referenceNumberInvalid;

    print("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + ", isValid: " + isValid + ", referenceNumber: " + referenceNumber + ", validateNumber: " + validateNumber + ", sum: " + sum + ", checkDigit: " + checkDigit + ", statusCode" + statusCode);

    return statusCode;
}
```

**This is how I create my script engine**

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
engine.eval(myScript);
```

**While Testing using Testng this works without any errors**

```
@Test(dataProvider = "validReferenceNumbers", timeOut = 3000)
public final void testValidReferenceNumber(String referenceNumber) throws NoSuchMethodException, ScriptException {
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("referenceNumber", referenceNumber);   
    Invocable invocable = (Invocable) engine;
    Object result = invocable.invokeFunction("validate", parameters);       
    Assert.assertEquals(statusCode, "000");
}

@DataProvider(name = "validReferenceNumbers")
private Iterator<Object[]> validReferenceNumbers() throws FileNotFoundException {
    Iterator<Object[]> testData = null;  
    // please assume that will be initilized correctly 
    return testData;
}
```

**Test Results1 - note that some data are repeated**

```
Thread: 10, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 38, checkDigit: 8, statusCode0000
Thread: 11, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 38, checkDigit: 8, statusCode0000
Thread: 12, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 17028884, validateNumber: 1702888, sum: 34, checkDigit: 4, statusCode0000
Thread: 13, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18028885, validateNumber: 1802888, sum: 35, checkDigit: 5, statusCode0000
Thread: 14, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 38, checkDigit: 8, statusCode0000
Thread: 15, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 17098881, validateNumber: 1709888, sum: 41, checkDigit: 1, statusCode0000
Thread: 16, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 17098881, validateNumber: 1709888, sum: 41, checkDigit: 1, statusCode0000
Thread: 17, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18028885, validateNumber: 1802888, sum: 35, checkDigit: 5, statusCode0000
Thread: 18, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 38, checkDigit: 8, statusCode0000
Thread: 19, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 17058887, validateNumber: 1705888, sum: 37, checkDigit: 7, statusCode0000
Thread: 20, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 38, checkDigit: 8, statusCode0000
Thread: 21, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 38, checkDigit: 8, statusCode0000
Thread: 22, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 38, checkDigit: 8, statusCode0000
Thread: 23, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 38, checkDigit: 8, statusCode0000
Thread: 24, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 38, checkDigit: 8, statusCode0000
Thread: 25, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18028885, validateNumber: 1802888, sum: 35, checkDigit: 5, statusCode0000
Thread: 26, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 38, checkDigit: 8, statusCode0000
Thread: 27, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18028885, validateNumber: 1802888, sum: 35, checkDigit: 5, statusCode0000
Thread: 28, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18028885, validateNumber: 1802888, sum: 35, checkDigit: 5, statusCode0000
Thread: 29, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18028885, validateNumber: 1802888, sum: 35, checkDigit: 5, statusCode0000
Thread: 30, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18028885, validateNumber: 1802888, sum: 35, checkDigit: 5, statusCode0000
Thread: 31, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18028885, validateNumber: 1802888, sum: 35, checkDigit: 5, statusCode0000
Thread: 32, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18028885, validateNumber: 1802888, sum: 35, checkDigit: 5, statusCode0000
Thread: 33, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 17058887, validateNumber: 1705888, sum: 37, checkDigit: 7, statusCode0000
Thread: 34, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18028885, validateNumber: 1802888, sum: 35, checkDigit: 5, statusCode0000
Thread: 35, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 38, checkDigit: 8, statusCode0000
Thread: 36, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 38, checkDigit: 8, statusCode0000
Thread: 37, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 38, checkDigit: 8, statusCode0000
Thread: 38, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 38, checkDigit: 8, statusCode0000
Thread: 39, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 38, checkDigit: 8, statusCode0000
Thread: 40, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 38, checkDigit: 8, statusCode0000
Thread: 41, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 38, checkDigit: 8, statusCode0000
Thread: 42, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 38, checkDigit: 8, statusCode0000
Thread: 43, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18028885, validateNumber: 1802888, sum: 35, checkDigit: 5, statusCode0000
Thread: 44, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 38, checkDigit: 8, statusCode0000
Thread: 45, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 38, checkDigit: 8, statusCode0000
Thread: 46, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 07034880, validateNumber: 0703488, sum: 30, checkDigit: 0, statusCode0000
Thread: 47, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 07034880, validateNumber: 0703488, sum: 30, checkDigit: 0, statusCode0000
Thread: 48, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 07009882, validateNumber: 0700988, sum: 32, checkDigit: 2, statusCode0000
```

**But if I add "parallel=true" to the @DataProvider my scripts starts to fail**

```
@Test(dataProvider = "validReferenceNumbers", timeOut = 3000)
public final void testValidReferenceNumber(String referenceNumber) throws NoSuchMethodException, ScriptException {
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("referenceNumber", referenceNumber);   
    Invocable invocable = (Invocable) engine;
    Object result = invocable.invokeFunction("validate", parameters);       
    Assert.assertEquals(statusCode, "000");
}

@DataProvider(name = "validReferenceNumbers", parallel=true)
private Iterator<Object[]> validReferenceNumbers() throws FileNotFoundException {
    Iterator<Object[]> testData = null;  
    // please assume that will be initilized correctly 
    return testData;
}
```

**Test Results2 - note that some data are repeated to show that the same reference number could fail randomly during the test**

```
Thread: 29, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 38, checkDigit: 8, statusCode0000
Thread: 22, isValid: false, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 1, checkDigit: 1, statusCode0001
Thread: 25, isValid: false, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 1, checkDigit: 1, statusCode0001
Thread: 21, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 17098881, validateNumber: 1709888, sum: 41, checkDigit: 1, statusCode0000
Thread: 27, isValid: false, referenceNumber: 18028885, validateNumber: 1802888, sum: 1, checkDigit: 1, statusCode0001
Thread: 20, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 17098881, validateNumber: 1709888, sum: 41, checkDigit: 1, statusCode0000
Thread: 26, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 17058887, validateNumber: 1705888, sum: 37, checkDigit: 7, statusCode0000
Thread: 24, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 17028884, validateNumber: 1702888, sum: 34, checkDigit: 4, statusCode0000
Thread: 23, isValid: false, referenceNumber: 18028885, validateNumber: 1802888, sum: 1, checkDigit: 1, statusCode0001
Thread: 28, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 38, checkDigit: 8, statusCode0000
Thread: 30, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 38, checkDigit: 8, statusCode0000
Thread: 32, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18028885, validateNumber: 1802888, sum: 35, checkDigit: 5, statusCode0000
Thread: 34, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18028885, validateNumber: 1802888, sum: 35, checkDigit: 5, statusCode0000
Thread: 31, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 38, checkDigit: 8, statusCode0000
Thread: 36, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18028885, validateNumber: 1802888, sum: 35, checkDigit: 5, statusCode0000
Thread: 38, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 38, checkDigit: 8, statusCode0000
Thread: 40, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18028885, validateNumber: 1802888, sum: 35, checkDigit: 5, statusCode0000
Thread: 42, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18028885, validateNumber: 1802888, sum: 35, checkDigit: 5, statusCode0000
Thread: 44, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 38, checkDigit: 8, statusCode0000
Thread: 33, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18028885, validateNumber: 1802888, sum: 35, checkDigit: 5, statusCode0000
Thread: 46, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 38, checkDigit: 8, statusCode0000
Thread: 48, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 38, checkDigit: 8, statusCode0000
Thread: 35, isValid: false, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 30, checkDigit: 0, statusCode0001
Thread: 50, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 38, checkDigit: 8, statusCode0000
Thread: 37, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 38, checkDigit: 8, statusCode0000
Thread: 39, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18028885, validateNumber: 1802888, sum: 35, checkDigit: 5, statusCode0000
Thread: 41, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 17058887, validateNumber: 1705888, sum: 37, checkDigit: 7, statusCode0000
Thread: 52, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 38, checkDigit: 8, statusCode0000
Thread: 54, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 38, checkDigit: 8, statusCode0000
Thread: 43, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18028885, validateNumber: 1802888, sum: 35, checkDigit: 5, statusCode0000
Thread: 45, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 38, checkDigit: 8, statusCode0000
Thread: 56, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 07009882, validateNumber: 0700988, sum: 32, checkDigit: 2, statusCode0000
Thread: 58, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 07034880, validateNumber: 0703488, sum: 30, checkDigit: 0, statusCode0000
Thread: 47, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 38, checkDigit: 8, statusCode0000
Thread: 49, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 38, checkDigit: 8, statusCode0000
Thread: 51, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 38, checkDigit: 8, statusCode0000
Thread: 53, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18028885, validateNumber: 1802888, sum: 35, checkDigit: 5, statusCode0000
Thread: 55, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 18058888, validateNumber: 1805888, sum: 38, checkDigit: 8, statusCode0000
Thread: 57, isValid: true, referenceNumber: 07034880, validateNumber: 0703488, sum: 30, checkDigit: 0, statusCode0000
```

Can anyone confirm if I can Initialize the ScriptEngine and allow it to be used in a multithreaded application. As you can see I use global script variables but those will not be modified during its execution. As our design revolves around a web service that calls this script internally.

**P.S.** In my understanding @DataProvider(parallel=true) is the proper way to test the multithreading, so If I am wrong please point it out.

> **Edit** Can anyone tell me how I can modify my code/script so that I can initialize the ScriptEngine and allow it to be used in a
>   multi-threaded
>   application. As I do not want to parse the script files over and over again.
>
> As I previously thought that if the script does not use global
>   variables to keep state it would be OK, but apparently that is not
>   enough.

Thanks

Comment: Nashorn is [not thread-safe](https://blogs.oracle.com/nashorn/entry/nashorn_multi_threading_and_mt). Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. Actually what I am asking is what is the proper approach  so that I can compile my script in and use it a multi-threaded application if it is even possible.

As I previously thought that if I put all my data manipulation inside the function and not use global variables to keep state that would be enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can initialize a `ScriptEngine` and use it in a multithreaded application.

Instead of `engine.eval(myScript);` you'll want to create a `CompiledScript` instance that you can later evaluate into `Bindings` instances:

```
Compilable compilable = (Compilable) engine;
CompiledScript script = compilable.compile(myScript);
```

And instead of using your `engine` as an `Invocable` you'll need to create a `Bindings` instance for each thread/test, evaluate the compiled script into it, get the [script object mirror](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/nashorn/jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/ScriptObjectMirror.html) that wraps the function, and then [call](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/nashorn/jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/ScriptObjectMirror.html#call-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-) the function:

```
@Test(dataProvider = "validReferenceNumbers", timeOut = 3000)
public final void testValidReferenceNumber(String referenceNumber) throws ScriptException {
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("referenceNumber", referenceNumber);
    Bindings bindings = engine.createBindings();
    script.eval(bindings);
    ScriptObjectMirror scriptObjectMirror = (ScriptObjectMirror) bindings.get("validate");
    Object result = scriptObjectMirror.call(null, parameters);
    /* insert result assertions here */
}
```

---

Sources:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/30159424/3255152
- [Reuse Nashorn ScriptEngine in Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27710407/reuse-nashorn-scriptengine-in-servlet#comment52833417_27712812)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32252478/3255152

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer this works for me. However, just one follow up question. What does the "this" parameter do in "scriptObjectMirror.call(this, parameters)"

Comment: @JefreyValencia, good question. After further investigation it looks like it becomes the `thiz` in `func.apply(thiz, args)` in JavaScript (see [Function.prototype.apply() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)). I've updated the code sample to use `null` instead. Thanks!

Comment: @ mfulton26, Thanks again

Comment: On a different note, calling CompiledScript.eval(Binding b) will apply changes to the bindings that are part of its contained ScriptEngine and not the ones that you pass as argument. Big difference there.

Comment: I tried doing exactly this and storing the ScriptObjectMIrror objects in a ThreadLocal object and it does not appear to be thread safe. This might be related to what @NishM mentioned above. Did anyone actually get this running in multiple threads?

Comment: It's been awhile since I looked at this but I found the code I used to experiment, etc. I've created a gist for it at https://gist.github.com/mfulton26/8c18f8cc1055f7137c4caf6ab751e89e. From what I can tell, running the tests in parallel behaves correctly.

Comment: @JesusAdoboLuzon My current setup is serving multiple threads. There is a ThreadLocal ScriptEngine with a ThreadLocal CompiledScripts cache. Bindings are copied and cached. Though i am not quite happy with the amount of objects created by this setup , jmeter tests are passing successfully for a million requests. ( 100 simultaneous threads).